# turning webcam into a stretching/scaling background image

Tags: javascript, css, html, background, webcam

connecting javascript to css div.

I've given some javascript that drives a webcam some new functions such as a delay and to only display when its uploaded successfully for an art project.

However I can no longer (for some stupid reason) connect it to my css without overriding the changes that i've made. **So that my simple web cam can be a background image that stretches to size on the page.**

(please see below)

I'd love to have the webcam background image be dynamically scaling but I don't think thats not possible in this context.

i'm sure you folks are more informed

**EDIT: SORRY I WAS NOT CLEAR ENOUGH.**
So i want to have the webcam javascript seen below to be as a background image on my page. i'm trying to make the webcam jpg turn into a background image. How ever i don't know how to connect the two with out over riding the changes i made.

so if the javascript could be connected to the css example below which should turn it into a stretching background image.

- it won't let me make the webcam connect to the css example shown. I can't understand how to get the css to all function.**

i hope that clears what i'm asking for.

something to do with the reference to the element by its ID?

**EDIT: END**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

function reloadBackground() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        d -= 15; // delay
    url = "http://www.panopticbedroom.com/templates/live.jpg?" + d;
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){
              $('#divBackground ').html('').append($(this));
        }


        img.src = url;
}

setInterval(reloadBackground, 1000);

function getDocHeight() {
    var doc = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(doc.body.scrollHeight, doc.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(doc.body.offsetHeight, doc.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(doc.body.clientHeight, doc.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

});
</script>
```

**and here is the relevant css:**

```
#divBackground {
background-image: url(http://www.panopticbedroom.com/templates/live.jpg)
position: absolute;
}

img#imgBackground {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

**I would really appreciate any advice!**

all the best,

louis

Comment: Would you please offer a slightly more precise indication of what behavior leads you to believe this code is not functioning as desired?

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear enough i added more information. i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Css Code to your img container

```
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='source of image',sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='source of image', sizingMethod='scale')"
```

Comment: thank you for your help but it doesn't seem to have taken effect. Perhaps it's something with in the javascript it's self.                              I'm going to try and ask someone on person. It will be easy to get the precise issue accross